# quantizer function from matlab in octave

Tags: matlab, octave, fixed-point

using matlab and the quantizer function you can represent a fixed-point number.

more information can be found here: https://de.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/quantize.html

currently i am using octave as a replacement for matlab, but was not able to use this function:

```
error: 'quantizer' undefined near line 1 column 5
```

i searched the internet and found the quantiz function, but this appears to be something else:
https://octave.sourceforge.io/communications/function/quantiz.html

is the quantizer function or something similar present in octave? or is this feature missing?

Comment: Have you tried the `uencode` in the **signal** toolbox of octave? It seems similar to what you are asking for.

Comment: There is also an octave-package `missing-functions`, that can be used to find out which matlab functions have not yet made it into octave. (Albeit, it seems that that package is not being actively maintained, since the last version came out over 10 years ago)